# no main manifest attribute error in multimodule app with gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jar

I have multimodule java/kotlin app with Gradle.
I wanna make `.jar` to launch my app in a terminal: like `java -jar mayApp.jar`

**How correct build `.jar` in multimodule app?**
My `.jar` generated by IDEA is not runs when I trying in terminal due to error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in /Users/me/IdeaProjects/MyProject/out/artifacts/MyProject_jar/MyProject.jar
```

project structure:

```
- :ApplicationName
    - :bot-app
        - src/main/java/main
            Main.java // psvm
        - src/main/resources
             - META-INF
                 MANIFEST.MF
        build.gradle // module's build 
        
    - :data
    - :utils
    build.gradle // application (root) build
```

[image: app-module organization]

So, in my multimodule project the main class is located in the `:bot-app` module.
Each module has its own `build.gradle` and in the root project I have `build.gradle` of the app;

**Module build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

group 'org.my_project'
version '2.4.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}
```

And it is my **root build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.Main"
    }
}
```

As u see, I added

```
tasks.withType(Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.Main"
    }
}
```

but it is not works for me. With 1 module it worked, but after refactoring to multimodule, no.

How build .jar in multimodule app?

**----
UPD:**

if I delete the `.gradle` folder in the root project and then try to run the app via IDEA it works well. But when I build artifacts via IDEA, jar is created but not works with the error:
`no main manifest attribute`

And each next build in IDEA is failed with error:
`Execution failed for task ':bot-app:jar'.

> Entry META-INF/bot-app.kotlin_module is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.`

If I delete `.gradle` again, build in IDEA works well.

Comment: `attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.Main.java"` -> `attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.Main"`,

Comment: Remove your file : `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Because you have used `tasks.jar { manifest { attributes ....` to set up and generate `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @life888888 I've removed `jar {manifest { ...`  block from module build.gradle file. Applied your changes and removed `MANIFEST.MF`. But now I have an error: `is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set`, I've added `duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE` to my root build.gradle in jar block, but it still is not working. Jar generating, but still with the same error `no main manifest attribute`.

Comment: @life888888 I've added the UPD block and updated my code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to delete:

```
tasks.withType(Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "main.Main"
    }
}
```

This code is extra for me.

Then create `MANIFEST.MF` at the root of the project.

Note: you must create it via `file->project structure->artifact->+`
and in the field `Directory for META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:` u must set root folder location (NOT module folder, but root)

Remove `.gradle`, clean, and build artifacts.